# Black background on Trebuchet

Tags: vanilla-android, trebuchet

On my current phone (HTC Wildfire S), with a AOSPA (Paranoid Android) 4.45 ROM, I installed Trebuchet, because Launcher3 lacks features, and other customs lauchers takes a lot of battery, while my current battery is already going down fast.

Here you can see a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image: trebuchet]
The background is black.

But it isn't supposed to be black:
[image: wall]

How can I show correctly my background?

Edit: Sometimes it show correctly on the bottom:
[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...
The APK I used was for the OnePlus One and had a MD5 of `2fd1a3e8f5a6ef44d1f14752b4caa5c9`.
I installed another APK, coming from [this ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2774542), and everything fixed itself (the MD5 was different: `3f465ccbfe8566479f863582671575c2`)

[image: pic]

The two APK had the same version number (1.0) and OnePlus One's was 1.97 MB while the working one was 1.9 MB o_0

Akward